# Ajax call for Datatables Serverside with Typo3 Extbase Controller function

Tags: ajax, datatable, typo3, extbase

I'm trying to make a Ajax call for Datatable Serverside with a Typo3 Extbase Controller for a frontend plugin but can't get the data in the table, instead only the following output:

```
{"sEcho":0,"iTotalRecords":"6","iTotalDisplayRecords":"6","aaData":[["1","Hans","Meier","51","2011-04-13","EUR200"],["2","Frank","Heinz","45","2004-02-17","EUR60"],["3","Katrin","Kohl","35","2011-08-17","EUR1000"],["4","Werner","Pertl","39","2013-11-19","USD499"],["5","Christina","Sinn","22","2015-03-09","GBP99"],["6","Klaus","Vienna","67","1991-01-15","EUR5000"]]}
```

I'm using the following view (list.html):

```
<f:layout name="Default" />
<f:section name="main">

<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Field 1</th>
            <th>Field 2</th>
            <th>Field 3</th>
            <th>Field 4</th>
            <th>Field 5</th>
            <th>Field 6</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Field 1</th>
            <th>Field 2</th>
            <th>Field 3</th>
            <th>Field 4</th>
            <th>Field 5</th>
            <th>Field 6</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript" src="typo3conf/ext/ffs_datatables/Resources/Public/ajaxFunctions.js"></script>

</f:section>
```

My js function (ajaxFunctions.js) used:

```
var MY_AJAX_ACTION_URL = '<f:uri.action action="list" controller="DatatableController" pageType="5000" />';

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').dataTable( {
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sAjaxSource": {
        type: 'POST',
        url: MY_AJAX_ACTION_URL         
    }
  } );
} );
```

.. and in my Controller:

```
namespace myVendor\FfsDatatables\Controller;

/**
* DatatableController
*/
class DatatableController extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Controller\ActionController {

/**
 * action list
 *
 * @return void
 */
 public function listAction() {
```

... and I'm including the following Syntax from: https://datatables.net/development/server-side/php_mysql here and exchanged echo with return ...

```
return json_encode( $output );
}
/**
 * action
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function Action() {
}
}
```

Typoscript used:

```
ajaxCall = PAGE
ajaxCall {
  typeNum = 5000
  config {
    disableAllHeaderCode = 1
    additionalHeaders = Content-type:application/json
    xhtml_cleaning = 0
    admPanel = 0
    debug = 0
    no_cache = 1
  }
}
```

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: You can also used eID call http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21139769/typo3-extbase-ajax-without-page-typenum#32225730

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you must add a line in your TypoScript where to get the output for your page:

```
ajaxCall = PAGE
ajaxCall {
  typeNum = 5000
  config {
    disableAllHeaderCode = 1
    additionalHeaders = Content-type:application/json
    xhtml_cleaning = 0
    admPanel = 0
    debug = 0
    no_cache = 1
  }
  10 < tt_content.list.20.yourextensionname_yourpluginname
}
```

In case that doesn't help you should consider not simply return your data in your action, but use the JsonView available since Extbase 6.2. Maybe this could give you further help:
[Typo3 extbase json output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27925797/typo3-extbase-json-output)